# Выборка с обрезанием

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица лог-посещений, в котором содержится название браузера. К примеру:

```
Chrome 24.0.1312.56
Chrome 24.0.1442.26
Opera 12.0
Opera 12.3
```

Мне нужна выборка уникальных браузеров до первой точки, т.е. из данного списка получим:

```
Chrome 24
Opera 12
```

В данном поле могут быть значения NULL

Раньше делал запрос на все уникальные, и в php обрезал до точки.

```
SELECT DISTINCT browser FROM `logs`
```

Можно ли такое провернуть в самом запросе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [функциями](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) работы со строками - думаю SUBSTR() и SUBSTRING_INDEX() Вам помогут.

Comment: Всё, спасибо, получилось вот так:

    SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX( browser,  '.', 1 ) FROM  `logs`

Answer (score 0):

Всё что запрашивается из БД, должно быть её же средствами преобразовано. Можно и `substr()`, можно и регулярнымии выражениями вытащить нужную информацию.

Comment: регулярными средствами БД? можете пример показать? :)

Comment: @IVsevolod, Регулярными *выражениями*! Но в MySQL я не функций подобных `regexp_substr()`.
См. на stackoverflow[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361457/mysql-return-matching-pattern-in-regexp-query]